# File organization/location within the computer

Tags: c++, structure, hierarchy, directory, organization

I have been learning c++ independently for about 3 months, and I have a question that has gone unanswered. How are the files organized within your computer so that the program knows where to look to find the files?

I know that you can save header files and source files as being separate from each other, but how does the program know where to look for these things? Where are they located? Where in the hierarchy (up or down, same folder) do they belong? Can I change where the computer looks for them?

This has been nagging at me for weeks and I have not found an answer. Does anyone know what I mean? Can you help?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: For standard library, compiler manages by itself.

For your includes, the compiler looks for them in the currently compiled source directory, or in the paths pointed by `CPATH` environment variable (or directories passed with `-I` option: ex `gcc -c -Imy_directory file.c`)

Comment: Undoubtedly there are holes in my knowledge, so I will work to fill them... but the compiler's name I don't know. I am working in Windows 10, but I am trying out Codeblocks and Visual Studio. I am self-learning this and most of the material I find skips right into coding without explaining things like folder structure, compiler names, etc.

Comment: By the way, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the Operation System ("OS"). There's an environment variable called PATH that instructs the compiler where to look at. On Linux and Mac there are a few typical folders, so the compiler looks inside these folders.

In addition to these default searches, the compiler also looks in the same folder as the source files live. And you can always tell the compiler where to look at first.

Comment: Okay, so the compiler is the thing that looks for the files, and it starts looking in the same folder that the source code file is located? I suppose I should have started my original question asking if anyone can point me toward a good resource that can explain in a high-level way how this stuff works.      Also, thanks.

Comment: Holy crap. I feel bad that I went this long without looking at this post.

Comment: Thanks for your guys’ help. Since the time I asked this question, I have made progress in my coding ability. I don’t need help n this one anymore.